# Filter nested JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON object structured like this:

```
var x = {
zy5EwY0caL3rPk4PXyX3: { name: 'Bob', completedDate: '2019-03-27T01:56:27.589Z'},
zy4HsKbHYZKtZNBMHdxu: { name: 'Tom', completedDate: '2019-04-10T01:56:27.589Z'},
zy0VPwMY51ksZaTFFIxL: { name: 'Jim', completedDate: '2019-05-01T01:56:27.589Z'},
zw6Xmv5PiNE4dmC19q2p: { name: 'Joe', completedDate: '2019-05-02T01:56:27.589Z'}
}
```

I want to run some javascript in a node script to filter and return only the objects where the completed data is within the last 10 days and return the following.

```
var filteredData = {
zy0VPwMY51ksZaTFFIxL: { name: 'Jim', completedDate: '2019-05-01T01:56:27.589Z'},
zw6Xmv5PiNE4dmC19q2p: { name: 'Joe', completedDate: '2019-05-02T01:56:27.589Z'}
}
```

I'm running into issues because the data is nested. I've tried using the .where function in underscore but I don't know the syntax to have it examine the nested elements.

Is there a simple way to get what I want?

Comment: What have you done to tackle this issue?

Comment: Can you show your code for the filtering? One level nested shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Phil Lachmann The lesson to be learned here is that you should also post your code/attempt at solving the problem. People expect to see some effort from the OP. Hundreds of people will be visiting this question in the future. They won't be able to see your problem, see what you did wrong. And IMO, that's wrong, because then there's no educational value in the question. They'll just copy/paste the first (or the most voted) answer/solution ... and the ignorance will spread :)

Comment: @akinuri Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Because your source data is not an array, you can't use `Array.filter`.

So what you could do is use `Object.entries` to iterate and then place into another object.

Below is a simple example.

```js
const x = {
zy5EwY0caL3rPk4PXyX3: { name: 'Bob', completedDate: '2019-03-27T01:56:27.589Z'},
zy4HsKbHYZKtZNBMHdxu: { name: 'Tom', completedDate: '2019-04-10T01:56:27.589Z'},
zy0VPwMY51ksZaTFFIxL: { name: 'Jim', completedDate: '2019-05-01T01:56:27.589Z'},
zw6Xmv5PiNE4dmC19q2p: { name: 'Joe', completedDate: '2019-05-02T01:56:27.589Z'}
};

const day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
//const now = Date.now();
//let's set a date time, so snippet will continue to work
//in the future, but Date.now() would be use
//for current time
const now = new Date("2019-05-08T14:29:27.589Z");

const ret = {};
for (const [k, v] of Object.entries(x)) {
  const tmc = new Date(v.completedDate);
  const diff = Math.abs(tmc.getTime() - now);
  if (diff < 10 * day) ret[k] = v;
}

console.log(ret);
```